# Insert of rows in android database not working

Tags: java, android, database

I have a serious problem with my android studio's app!

I have created a db with two table. The problem happen when I insert the data. Infact, when I insert the data in the form, the previous one are deleted!

------------For example-------------------

**First insertion:**

Name --> a
Password --> a

**Second insertion:**
Name --> b
Password --> b

But the first insertion is canceled!

I hope that anyone help me... I put some code to understand my problem:

**DatabaseOperation.java**

```
private static final String CREATETABLE_QUERY_USER =
        "CREATE TABLE " + UserContact.DatabaseInfo.TABLE_USER + " ( "
                + UserContact.UserInfo.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + UserContact.UserInfo.USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserContact.UserInfo.PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserContact.UserInfo.EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserContact.UserInfo.PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL "
                + " );"
        ;

private static final String CREATETABLE_QUERY_PASSWORD =
        "CREATE TABLE " + UserContact.DatabaseInfo.TABLE_PASS + " ( "
                + UserContact.PasswordTable.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + UserContact.PasswordTable.NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserContact.PasswordTable.POSTERPASSWORD + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + UserContact.PasswordTable.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + UserContact.PasswordTable.PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL "
                //+ " FOREIGN KEY(" + UserContact.PasswordTable.ID + ") REFERENCES " + UserContact.DatabaseInfo.TABLE_USER + "(" + UserContact.UserInfo.ID +")
                + " );"
        ;
public void addUser(SQLiteDatabase db, String username, String password, String email, String phone){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.clear();
    contentValues.put(UserContact.UserInfo.USERNAME, username);
    contentValues.put(UserContact.UserInfo.PASSWORD, password);
    contentValues.put(UserContact.UserInfo.EMAIL, email);
    contentValues.put(UserContact.UserInfo.PHONE_NUMBER, phone);
    db.insert(UserContact.DatabaseInfo.TABLE_USER, null, contentValues);
}

public void addPassword(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String note, String password, int posterpassword){

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.clear();

    if(password.length() > 0){
        contentValues.put(UserContact.PasswordTable.POSTERPASSWORD, posterpassword);
        contentValues.put(UserContact.PasswordTable.NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(UserContact.PasswordTable.DESCRIPTION, note);
        contentValues.put(UserContact.PasswordTable.PASSWORD, password);

        db.insert(UserContact.DatabaseInfo.TABLE_PASS, null, contentValues);
        Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", " INSERT PASSWORD successfull in " + UserContact.DatabaseInfo.TABLE_PASS + "...");
    }
}
```

**NewContact.java**

```
String name      = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
String password  = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
String mail      = emailEditText.getText().toString();
String phone     = phoneEditText.getText().toString();

//Add user to database
String dbFile = getDatabasePath(UserContact.DatabaseInfo.DB_NAME).getPath();
databaseOperations = new DatabaseOperations(context);
sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, UserContact.DatabaseInfo.password, null);
sqLiteDatabase = databaseOperations.getWritableDatabase(UserContact.DatabaseInfo.password);
databaseOperations.addUser(sqLiteDatabase, name, password, mail, phone);
Log.e("New Contact: " , "Success! -> username: " + name + ", password: " + password);
//End to add user----------------------------------

//After registration, return to authentication page
Intent intent_authenticationPage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AuthenticationPage.class);
startActivity(intent_authenticationPage);
```

Comment: why do you assign sqLiteDatabase twice?

Comment: @bob0the0mighty Could you explain? I don't understand

Do you mean about the two rows where appears the openOrCreate?

Comment: In NewContact.java, you set sqLiteDatabase on line 9, then set it again on line 10. It doesn't look like the two lines are related. Perhaps you use line 9 to initialize the database, if it doesn't exist, since you use openOrCreateDatabase.

Comment: How can I write? I haven't got any idea @bob0the0mighty

Comment: It works! I introduce some control of the existing of the db and now work
I only delete the instruction: "openOrCreate"

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your database structure but anyways try changing the `CREATE TABLE` syntax from

```
CREATE TABLE <table_name>(...)
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_name>(...)
```

Comment: Why this line is required `sqLiteDatabase = databaseOperations.getWritableDatabase` since you also tried `sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase` ?

Comment: I follow a tutorial, but I don't know
It seems wrong, however I don't know to fix it

Comment: It works! I introduce some control of the existing of the db and now work
I only delete the instruction: "openOrCreate"

Thanks a lot!!